# Custom labelling of variables under an equation TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to make this: (your prerogative as to the approach). It is basically labelling an equation:

`\begin{equation}
Y\simeq Y(\lambda,\,h,\,A,\,V,\,\beta,n)
\end{equation}`

[image]

How about `TikZ` do you think that would do it?

Comment: [This `texample`](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/beamer-arrows/) may be of interest. It uses `beamer`, but nothing prevents you from using another class.

Comment: Thanks @Jubobs that was my first port of call. It looks a bit too ad-hoc, I was really wondering if something less fancy was out there?

Comment: @Jubobs thank your making that for me. I really appreciate it! Incidentally, is it possible to place half of the bullet points on one side and half on the other side?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but I think this moves the goalpost a bit, which is not really what we want on TeX.SE. Why don't you post it as another question? I'll do my best to answer it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably not the best style in the world, but you get the idea. Two compilations are necessary.

Reference: http://texample.net/tikz/examples/beamer-arrows/

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} %

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\tikzset{%
    every picture/.style={remember picture},%
    na/.style={baseline=-.5ex},%
}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}       
Y \simeq Y(
    \tikz[baseline]{
        \node[fill=blue!20,anchor=base] (lambda1)
    {$\lambda$};
    },
    \tikz[baseline]{
        \node[fill=red!20,anchor=base] (h1)
    {$h$};
    },
    \tikz[baseline]{
        \node[fill=green!20,anchor=base] (A1)
    {$A$};
    },
    \tikz[baseline]{
        \node[fill=yellow!20,anchor=base] (V1)
    {$V$};
    },
    \tikz[baseline]{
        \node[fill=magenta!20,anchor=base] (beta1)
    {$\beta$};
    },
    \tikz[baseline]{
        \node[fill=cyan!20,anchor=base] (n1)
    {$n$};
    }
)
\end{equation*}
\begin{itemize}
    \item lambda blah blah
        \tikz[na]\node [coordinate] (lambda2) {};
    \item h blah blah
        \tikz[na]\node [coordinate] (h2) {};
    \item A blah blah
        \tikz[na]\node [coordinate] (A2) {};
    \item V blah blah
        \tikz[na]\node [coordinate] (V2) {};
    \item beta blah blah
        \tikz[na]\node [coordinate] (beta2) {};
    \item n blah blah
        \tikz[na]\node [coordinate] (n2) {};
\end{itemize}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \path[->] (lambda2) edge [bend right] (lambda1);
        \path[->] (h2)      edge [bend right] (h1);
        \path[->] (A2)      edge [bend right] (A1);
        \path[->] (V2)      edge [bend right] (V1);
        \path[->] (beta2)   edge [bend right] (beta1);
        \path[->] (n2)      edge [bend right] (n1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Edit**: Here is a more automated, albeit not very flexible solution; nothing prevents you from customising my `\eqexplanation` command further to better suit your needs, though.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\eqexplanation[3]{% % #1: whatever precedes the first delimiter
                                % #2: list of argument/description
                                %       (do not use "/" in description!)
                                % #3: unique identifier (choose it carefully)
    \tikzset{%
        every picture/.style={remember picture},%
        na/.style={baseline=-.5ex},%
    }
    \[
        #1%
        ( % <---- opening delimiter
        \foreach \myarg/\mydescription [count=\myargi] in #2{%
            \ifnum\myargi=1\else,\fi% print a comma for all but first element of #1
            \tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor=base] (#3A\myargi){$\myarg$};}%
        }%
        ) % <---- closing delimiter
    \]
    where
    \begin{itemize}
        \foreach \myarg/\mydescription [count=\myargi] in #2{%
            \item $\myarg$ \mydescription                   \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (#3B\myargi) {};
        }
    \end{itemize}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \foreach \myarg/\mydescription [count=\myargi] in #2{%
            \path[->] (#3B\myargi) edge[bend right] (#3A\myargi) {};%
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\def\myarglist{%
    \lambda/is some wavelength,%
    h/is some height,%
    A/is some area,%
    V/is some volume,%
    \beta/is some angle,%
    n/is some integer%
}
\eqexplanation{Y \simeq Y}{\myarglist}{egreg}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know if it breaks something regarding the way `TeX` treats math symbols (`\mathop`, `mathbin`, etc.)?

Comment: @cjorssen Not that I know of. Have you experienced problems?

Comment: No but I've never used such tricks fearing to do something wrong `:)`.